# How to derive public object interface from $this?

Tags: php, oop

This is a strip-down version of my template class, focusing on executing file in a restricted scope `$env`:

```
class Template {
    /**
     * Defines new scope for template execution using $evn variables and
     * executes the template script in an output buffer.
     *
     * @param string $file File name (excluding file extension) relavite to the template directory.
     * @param array $env Variables populated in the template scope.
     * @return string Template output.
     */
    public function render ($file, array $env = []) {
        $env['template'] = $this;

        return self::render($file, $env);
    }

    /**
     * The additional static render method is used to prevent
     * exposing $this and other Template properties to the template scope.
     * Two variables (file and env) are captured using func_get_arg for
     * the same reason of not exposing them to the template scope.
     *
     * @return string Template output.
     */
    static private function render () {
        extract(func_get_arg(1), \EXTR_REFS);

        ob_start();
        require func_get_arg(0);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    private function test () { /* I do not want $template to have access to this */ }
}
```

In the template itself, I'd like to expose instance of the Template class used to execute the script. This can be done, e.g.

```
$template = new Template();
$template->render('foo', ['template' => $template]);
```

However, that requires explicitly capturing and passing `$template` instance at the time of constructing the Template object.

However, if I do it inside the `render` method:

```
$env['template'] = $this;
```

Then `$template` has access to private Template methods, e.g. `test`.

Is there a way to derive from `$this` instance of object that has access only to public methods?

Comment: You can create class with private methods that Template class will inherit from.
This way the private methods will be accessed through parent class, but not Template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a rendering context that's a separate class altogether; here's how it changes the `Template::render()` function:

```
public function render ($file, array $env = []) {
    return RenderContext::run($file, $this, $env);
}
```

And this is the shell class:

```
class RenderContext
{
    static function run($file, $template, $env)
    {
        extract($env);

        ob_start();
        require $file;

        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are still passing `$this` to `run` method, therefore `$template` will allow access to the private methods.

Comment: It won't allow acces to Template's private properties or methods.

Comment: You are right, it won't. http://3v4l.org/0tUXF However, I am puzzled why? After all, you are passing `$this` to the method.